# Convert HashMap to Associative Array Android Retrofit Laravel

Tags: android, laravel, retrofit

I am using Retrofit To Pass HashMap to Laravel Restful API.  I need help to catch this hashmap and convert it to an associative array so I can loop through and insert into MySql database.  Please see the code below.

**Android**

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("create_phone_contacts")
Call<ResponseBody> createPhoneContacts(
        @Field("id") String id,
        @FieldMap Map<String, String> phoneContactPhones,
        @FieldMap Map<String, String> phoneContactEmails

);
```

**Laravel**

```
class CreatePhoneContactsController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {

        $phoneContactsPhones = new PhoneContactsPhonesModel;
        $phoneContactsPhones->mysql_user_id = $request->id;
        $phoneContactsPhones->phone = $request->phone;
        $phoneContactsPhones->name = $request->name;
        $phoneContactsPhones->save();

        $phoneContactsEmails = new PhoneContactsEmailsModel;
        $phoneContactsEmails->mysql_user_id = $request->id;
        $phoneContactsEmails->email = $request->email;
        $phoneContactsEmails->name = $request->name;
        $phoneContactsEmails->save();

        if ($phoneContactsPhones->save() && $phoneContactsEmails->save()) {

            return ['success' => 'Phone Contacts Created'];

        } else {

            return ['failure' => 'Phone Contacts Failure'];

        }

    }
}
```

Here I am just catching the fields, how should I catch the hashmap in Laravel and convert it into associative array... thanks....

Comment: can you `dd($request->all())` to see how the request input is being handled

Comment: converting the map to json object and sending it it is going, now the php part is left to loop and insert into mysql in laravel

Comment: would love to see what the output of `$request->all()` is

Comment: @lagox Using $data = dd($request->all());
return $data;  Gives: array:1 [
  "json" => "{'name':'John', 'age':31, 'city':'New York'}"
]

Comment: @lagbox for $request->all() the result is : {"json":"{'name':'John', 'age':31, 'city':'New York'}"}

Comment: @lagbox i see what you mean... the json being sent has some special characters and maybe because of this laravel is unable to parse it... should i use gson serialization please guide me in the right direction, the code i will search myself..

Comment: is `{"name": "John", "age": 31, "city": "New York"}` not what you were expecting? are you expecting another object with another set of data or something?

Comment: its putting some backslashes in the response body.. but in postman it is returning this it is wierd

Comment: where does email and phone come into play?

Comment: yes this is what i am expecting...

Comment: @lagbox There was a problem with nameValuePairs being added because of JSON object instead of Map, and hence sending the map directly did the trick... that was the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working now, it will take the map send it via retrofit and insert into mysql.

**Activity**

```
    Call<JsonObject> call = RetrofitMySql
            .getInstance()
            .getApi()
            .createPhoneContacts(mySqlUserId,
                                 namePhoneMap);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call,
                               Response<JsonObject> response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                Log.d("",
                      "JsonReturned: " + jsonObject);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call,
                              Throwable t) {
            Log.d("response",
                  "Getting response from server : " + t);
        }
    });
```

**API**

```
@POST("create_phone_contacts/{id}")
Call<JsonObject> createPhoneContacts(
        @Path("id") String id,
        @Body Map<String, String> namePhoneMap

);
```

**Laravel**

```
public function create(Request $request, $id)
{


    $json = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
        $users = new PhoneContactsPhonesModel;// ---> here
        $users->mysql_user_id = $id;
        $users->phone = $key;
        $users->name = $value;
        $users->save();

    }

}
```